# Wrap a code block in HTML tags or other arbitrary code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not sure what the best way to word this question is. It is possibly why I am on StackOverflow because I cannot find a result on Google. Let me give it a try.

Assume I have the following HTML in my editor:

```
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
```

Is there a way to highlight all three of those lines, perhaps (on MacOS) using `cmd+L` and wrap them conveniently in `<ul></ul>` tags? Right now my process for doing this includes:

1. writing out `<ul></ul>` above the HTML I want to wrap. Hit return for a line break between the two tags I want to embed content between.
2. select the code block I want to embed between those tags using `cmd+L`
3. on MacOS, hit `option+Up Arrow Key` to move it in between the tags.

This is kind of awkward. Is there a simpler keyboard shortcut to do this, not just for HTML but for any code? It would be great to be able to take code like this:

`car.turnLeft()`

and simply wrap it in a condition very quickly without following the 3 non-optimal steps above:

```
if (car.isHeadedWrongDirection()) {
    car.turnLeft()
}
```

The example above is forcefully contrived, but I think it makes the point for what I would like to accomplish in the editor.

Comment: `Emmet: Wrap with Abbrviation` can do this for HTML. Select all the `li` tags (not multi cursor) and call the command and enter the required tag.

Comment: @rioV8 this is perfect for HTML. I wonder if there is a similar way of wrapping non-HTML content, though.

Comment: You can have a look at the extension Regex Text Generator ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen ) you can do a lot of it using the selected text

Comment: Or use snippets with `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form for wrapping is to use `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT` within a snippet.  Like

```
"if wrap": {
  "prefix": "*s",
  "body": [

      "if car.$1()) {",
      "\t${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}",
      "}"
  ],
  "description": "Wrap selection in if statement"
},
```

That snippet goes into one of your snippet files, see [create a snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).

Because the snippet trigger, here `*s` will negate your selection, you will need to trigger the snippet with a keybinding, in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+i",         // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {

    "name": "if wrap"   // the name you gave your snippet
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

Now select the text you want to wrap and trigger the keybinding <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

---

There are other ways to avoid having to select the text first that you want to wrap or to not actually consume the text - if you wanted to add the if wrap below the text for example.